# AutoMapper one source object to multiple destination objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I've got a source model defined as

```
public class SourceRoot
{
    ...
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Organisation
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string Currency { get; set; }   
    public double SupplementaryAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal BaseConversionRate { get; set; }
}
```

and a destination defined as:

```
public class DestinationRoot
{
    ...
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
    public ContributesTo ContributesTo { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}

public class ContributesTo
{
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public double SupplementaryAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal BaseConversionRate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map from the `SourceRoot` to the `DestinationRoot` add copy from the source `Organisation` to the destination `Organisation` AND `ContributesTo`.

I have the following configuration for AutoMapper:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration RegisterMappings()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
            {   
                cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>();
            });

        return config;
    }
}

public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.CreateMap<SourceRoot, DestinationRoot>();        
        this.CreateMap<Source.Organisation, Destination.Organisation>();
        this.CreateMap<Source.Organisation, Destination.ContributesTo>();
    }
}
```

Using this current profile the `Organisation` gets mapped but the `ContributesTo` comes out as null. 
Note that I'm using version 4.2 of AutoMapper where the static methods have been deprecated so trying to steer away from that. Normally I would do:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceRoot, DestinationRoot>()
            .ForMember(d => d.ContributesTo, opt => opt.MapFrom( s=> Mapper.Map<ContributesTo>(s.Organisation)));
```

But this is not advised anymore (referencing the static methods). Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add mapping for `ContributesTo` destination member:

```
protected override void Configure ()
{
    CreateMap<Source.SourceRoot, Destination.DestinationRoot>()
        .ForMember(d => d.ContributesTo, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Organisation));

    CreateMap<Source.Organisation, Destination.Organisation>();
    CreateMap<Source.Organisation, Destination.ContributesTo>();
}
```

Otherwise Automapper finds that both source and destinaton roots have property `Organisation` and it maps only this property. Automapper cannot understand that it should use one property of source to map several properties of destination (which do not match by name). Note that you don't need to specify mapping for `Organisation` member, because it matches property name in destination object.

Comment: It's one of those things that you look too hard at trying to find a solution (like I was trying to do the map for it) when the answer is really simple! Thanks for that!